# Adding datas to Jtable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

How to update data to my Jtable without loosing the data when program ends

Basically iam preparing a app for storing data related to the account no. Person name joining date, initial amount etc.but i could only store 1 data in a row. When i enter the next data. The former will gets erased. Whats the solution for it

Comment: Write the data to a file before exiting.  Read from that file, if it exists, when starting.

Comment: Use a database?

Comment: Either use a database to store the information, either locally or on a server, then get the data from there when starting, or store the information in a file like a .csv file and load the data from there.